# I want to log out the user and send him to another activity

Tags: android, google-signin

I am checking in my first Activity if the user has already logged in so that we can send him to second activity again without making him log in using the Google sign in option. But in the second Activity, when the user signs out, they want to go to the register screen i.e the first Activity. When we reach there the code finds out that there was already a login and sends the user back to the second screen. How do I fix it?

It checks the login in the first Activity like this.

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
if (account != null){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Already logged in!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    goToNextActivity();
}
```

And logs out from the second Activty like this

```
fAuth.signOut();
```

How I go from the first Activty to the second Activity

```
public void goToNextActivity(){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

How I go from the second Activity to the first Activty

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), registerActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: do you save user to the sharedpreferences ?

Comment: No I save the user in firebase

Comment: then when you logout you wanna tell firebase that you have logged out the user

Comment: Yes i did that like fAuth.signOut();

Comment: Much easier way is to go to the second activity directly and do all the logic from there. In the `onCreate` of your second Activity, you can check if the user has logged in. If not, you can start the first Activity and call clear top. Same goes for when the users logs out

Comment: Thanks @HB It worked out.

Comment: You are welcome